# Pandas df.idmax failing in 0.22.0 version

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas Version: 0.22.0
My code which worked in 0.20 version

```
    pvt = df.pivot_table(columns='period', values='qty', aggfunc='sum')
    df['qty'] = df['qty'].astype(float)
    print pvt
    d = pvt.idxmax(axis = 1)
```

pvt.idmax worked fine in my previous version.
Now it is giving error "reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype"
Do i need to downgrade my pandas version ?

Comment: Maybe is necessary convert `period`s in columns to `string`s like `df.columns=df.columns.to_series().astype(str)` or something like `df.columns= df.columns.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Or maybe need `pvt['qty'] = pvt['qty'].astype(float)` instead `df['qty'] = df['qty'].astype(float)` - typo problem

Answer (score 3):

You should apply .astype(float) before you pivot the df.
Maybe the new version of pandas is more strict about dtypes.
Try this :

```
df['qty'] = df['qty'].astype(float)
pvt = df.pivot_table(columns='period', values='qty', aggfunc='sum')
print pvt
d = pvt.idxmax(axis = 1)
```